# Files and Libraries As Lightning Component

Tags: files, libraries

I want to include a Visualforce component on a Lightning Record Page that routes to a specific file library.  As neither Files nor Libraries are Objects, I am having some trouble developing this component.  Also there is not much documentation on Files and Libraries.

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

The premise of the question is mistaken. Files and Libraries are both objects.

For a quick overview of the admittedly complex object model for Salesforce's Content system, review the [ERD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm#sforce_api_erd_content). You're probably specifically interested in [`ContentWorkspace`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm), which is a library, and [`ContentDocument`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm), which is a file.

The SOAP Reference, to which I link above, is often the most useful source on the intricacies of interacting with these objects, some of which come with unique behaviors and restrictions.